# Google search keeps closing

Tags: google, search

Nitrogen ROM 7.1 on a Nexus 6

I've been having an issue where I will hold the home button down to pull up search, tap on the search bar to bring up the keyboard, and within a few seconds the search bar clears itself and closes the keyboard.

Everyone in the Nitrogen XDA thread thought it was maybe a Substratum theme causing the issue though one user did report the same thing. I uninstalled the theme and the problem persisted. Basically I think I narrowed it down to having Adaway installed, which coincidentally the other user reporting the same issue had installed as well.

I went to the Adaway thread and so far only 1 reply saying it couldn't possibly be that. So I reflashed my ROM and gapps, and everything was working OK. I reinstalled Adaway and bam, the issue came back up.

I made a screen recording to show you the issue in action. The first instance I don't type anything, just wait, and it closes itself. The second time I starting typing and it happens again. So basically every time I open search I have to tap the search bar, wait for the keyboard to close, then tap the search bar again, then it works... until i need to search something else.

[Here is the screen recording.](https://streamable.com/e/sz98)

And here is a [logcat](http://pastebin.com/GSsZLqqk) of the crash.

12-03 10:01:36.449   824  1796 seems to be what it spits out when the keyboard actually closes.

Thanks in advance, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Yeah must be a nougat thing. Keeps happening to me too

Comment: Dude, same exact issue. I'm on a brand new nexus 5x with android 7.0, and I'm using Swype keyboard. Very annoying. I'm not sure what Adaway is. Don't think I have it.

Comment: Same issue here, a lot of people are experiencing it.

Comment: I have the same problem on my stock nexus 5 with the latest android version installed that is available for nexus 5.